# Netbeans Ide ')' expected

Tags: java, netbeans

```
private void btnUserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   String strName,strFood,strAge; 
   strName=this.txtDogsname.getText();
   strFood=this.txtDogsfood.getText();
   int age= Integer.parseInt(txtDogsage.getText());
   //Changes string to int
   this.lbloutput.setText("The Dog's name is "+strName+". "+ strName+"'s favourite food is "+ strFood+". "+strName+"'s Age in human years is"+(age*7);" years old.");
}
```

Can't seem to catch where I missed it. Thanks for the help in advance.

this.lbloutput.setText("The Dog's name is "+strName+". "+ strName+"'s favourite food is "+ strFood+". "+strName+"'s Age in human years is"+(age*7);" years old.");

^the line that seems to be the problem

Comment: `...Age in human years is"+(age*7);" years old.")` ... see any problems here?

Comment: +(age*7); you have already terminated the statement here. Rest of the text becomes a new statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
this.lbloutput.setText("The Dog's name is "+strName+". "+ strName+"'s favourite food is "+ strFood+". "+strName+"'s Age in human years is"+(age*7);" years old.");
```

to

```
this.lbloutput.setText("The Dog's name is "+strName+". "+ strName+"'s favourite food is "+ strFood+". "+strName+"'s Age in human years is"+(age*7)+" years old.");
```

`"+(age*7);" years old"`. The  `;` was the problem. Use `+` the concatenation was not proper.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **;** after `(age*7)`. Remove it and add **+**, it should work

Comment: This could have easily been a comment and a vote to close for a typographical error in my humble opinion. Still, if you made the work to answer the question, please also explain **why** this helps solving the problem over just stating it does. Currently this is no better than a code paste.